# AWS Route 53 setting www prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I want to host a site on Amazon S3 servers (and use Route53 as a DNS).

I followed the tutorial from AWS page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html.

Say, that my website is ex.ample.pl. I want it to be reachable from ex.ample.pl and www.ex.ample.pl.

What I did:

- in S3 created bucket for ex.ample.pl,
- in S3 created bucket for www.ex.ample.pl and redirected it to ex.ample.pl,
- in Route53 created hosted zones for ex.ample.pl and www.ex.ample.pl,
- for domain registrar I gave NS records for ex.ample.pl,
- in Route53 in zone www.ex.ample.pl settings are like in
  [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oOZF.png) . NS are not like in ex.ample.pl

As an effect, I can access the site at ex.ample.pl, but I can't at www.ex.ample.pl. Bucket redirection works for sure, there must be some error in DNS setup. Do you know what may cause this problem?